# How to pass mysql row count in a variable to android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

Using php script to query the mysql database with no problem.  However I'm unable to parse the result with JSON and send it back to android.  I have no problem encoding/parsing arrays - is a single variable different?  Is there a better way to send a row count back to android?

php code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logs WHERE uid = '$uid' AND tableid = '$tid'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo json_encode($num_rows);
```

Comment: Please do not continue using mysql_-class functions. Either use mysqli_, MYSQLI::, or PDO. See php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php and php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: a json encode int is just an int - your client side logic is the code to show and debug

Comment: `json_encode($num_rows)` is supposed to output something like a plain integer number, e.g. `1234`. If you cannot parse this, you android code is to blame, unless you output more than this. Have you checked the script output manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can just select the number of rows in your query.

SELECT COUNT(*) ...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking, the above code will just output the number of rows, To make it accessible in android app, you have to make it as key value pair, So that you can access the row number using the key as given below,

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logs WHERE uid = '$uid' AND tableid = '$tid'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$output = array("count" => $num_rows);
echo json_encode($output);
```

This will output {"count":123}